# Add Content in HTML Pages Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large project having 50000 pages (20000 aspx forms, 10000 asp forms and 10000 html page. Now I have to add some content after body tag in all pages and I have only 2 days for that. Please suggest how to achieve ?

Comment: Bulk replacement with a text editor or your IDE might work, but your question is too broad. It would be helpful to add information on the nature of your code control. If there's really 10k HTML documents, surely they share some features instead of being all stand-alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add content you don't necessarily need to edit HTML - if you have a javascript file common to all these files, you can edit it to add content dynamically.

For example:

```
var p=document.createElement("p");
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Here is an additional paragraph at the end of the body"));
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Notepad++ I would recommend using the Find in Files tool.
For instance let's say you want to add an  tag after the body tags.

1. Press `CTRL+F`
2. Go to the Find in Files tab
3. In "Find what" insert
4. In "Replace with" insert the body tag and the tag you want to add (for instance:
5. Choose the directory which your files are in.
6. Make sure "In all sub-folders" is checked
7. Press on the button "Replace in Files"

**Make sure that you have all the files opened in the editor**

Comment: @Teemu You are right I will change my answer. It defenitly a better way to do that